# Mongodb - populate with limit on items and get total count of those items

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a query looking like this:

```
const articles = await Article.find(query)
    .populate({
      path: 'votedUsers', // array of users id
      select: 'title name username',
      options: {
        limit: 3, 
        sort: { createdAt: -1 },
      },
    })
    .exec()
```

Result:

```
[
 {
   title: 'Article title',
   votedUsers: [,,], // array of populated users with limit of 3
   totalCountVoted: 200 // need to add this field 
 }
]
```

I want to find articles and populate `votedUsers` property but with limit to 3 users, but at the same time 
I need to know how many ids were in `votedUsers` property.

For example it can be 200 users that voted on that article, but I just need to know the number and populate only 3 of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following aggregation using the [match](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/), [lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/), [project](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project) stages, and   [slice](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/slice/)  and [size](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/size) operators:

(Please note that the "users" value in lookup from must be the physical collection name.)

```
app.get("/article", async (req, res) => {
  const data = await Article.aggregate([
    {
      $match: {
        category: "Category1"
      }
    },
    {
      $lookup: {
        from: "users",
        localField: "votedUsers",
        foreignField: "_id",
        as: "users"
      }
    },
    {
      $project: {
        title: 1,
        votedUsers: { $slice: ["$users", 3] },
        totalCountVoted: { $size: "$users" }
      }
    }
  ]);

  res.send(data);
});
```

This will give you a result like this:

```
[
    {
        "_id": "5dded78f8f30c402b0fac309",
        "title": "Article1",
        "votedUsers": [
            {
                "_id": "5dded60a84523642bc27f511",
                "__v": 0,
                "name": "User1"
            },
            {
                "_id": "5dded61384523642bc27f512",
                "__v": 0,
                "name": "User2"
            },
            {
                "_id": "5dded61b84523642bc27f513",
                "__v": 0,
                "name": "User3"
            }
        ],
        "totalCountVoted": 8
    },
    {
        "_id": "5dded7c18f30c402b0fac30a",
        "title": "Article2",
        "votedUsers": [
            {
                "_id": "5dded61b84523642bc27f513",
                "__v": 0,
                "name": "User3"
            },
            {
                "_id": "5dded63c84523642bc27f514",
                "__v": 0,
                "name": "User4"
            },
            {
                "_id": "5dded64484523642bc27f515",
                "__v": 0,
                "name": "User5"
            }
        ],
        "totalCountVoted": 8
    }
]
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/YolF0sRmNCj)